# How to scroll to certain row in QML TreeView

Tags: qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols

In `TreeView`, selecting a row by clicking it.
But I want to focus the row in `TreeView` by indicating the row `QModelIndex` and `roleName`.

I found similar function in `ListView`:

```
positionViewAtIndex(int index, PositionMode mode)
```

How to do this in `TreeView`?

Comment: I have never used the `TreeView` so this is just me, guessing in the dark. **1. Idea** What you might try is to set the `currentIndex` - this requires you to be able to create a valid `QModelIndex` which is otherwise mostly hidden from QML. You might need to expose a method to create it from your model to QML. I don't know whether this will result in a scrolling. **2. Idea** `TableView` inherits `ScrollView` which has a `Flickable` as `flickableItem`. Get the position of the delegate on the `Flickable.contentItem` and set the positioning of the `contentItem` in the `Flickable` accordingly.

Comment: If you give me a MVCE (including a model and view), I would give it a shot to solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use hidden variable __listView.

```
__listView.positionViewAtIndex(row, mode)
```