# Why some QtQuick Controls have the hidden variable?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

This question is actually come from [How to scroll to certain row in QML TreeView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46441998/how-to-scroll-to-certain-row-in-qml-treeview/49558246). Some properties of `QtQuick` items are hidden like `__listView` in `TreeView`.
I understand there are some complex UI components based on some other basic one.

**Qt** gives the accessibility to use it but didn't mention it in the document, such hidden properties did work well as expected. So why **Qt** hide the properties? Shall I use it?

Comment: Because it is important to make our lives miserable. QML APIs are often notorious for the lack of configurability. Someone somewhere assumed that one size should fit all, sandbagging the way to additional functionality someone else might envision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a convention created at the beginning of QML in Qt4 that we can find in this [link](https://qt.developpez.com/doc/4.7/qml-coding-conventions/), which seems not documented in Qt5:

> **Private Properties**
>
> QML and JavaScript do not enforce private properties like C++. There
>   is a need to hide these private properties, for example, when the
>   properties are part of the implementation. As a convention, private
>   properties begin with two underscore characters. For example, __area,
>   is a property that is accessible but is not meant for public use. Note
>   that QML and JavaScript will grant the user access to these
>   properties.
>
> ```
>  Item {
>      id: component
>      width: 40; height: 50
>      property real __area: width * height * 0.5    //not meant for outside use
>  }
> ```